# Why can't I use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in XAML at design time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, globalization

I have the following XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static s:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=Date: {0:dddd, MMMM dd}}"/>
```

`s:DateTime.Now` with `xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` works fine at runtime as well as in design mode (Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise).

But if I try the same with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, then this works at runtime only and gives me an error in design mode (`xmlns:c="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"`):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static s:DateTime.Now}, ConverterCulture={x:Static c:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}, StringFormat=Date: {0:dddd, MMMM dd}}"/>
```

I'm not looking for a workaround. I am only trying to understand the difference between `DateTime.Now` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and why one of them works and the other one doesn't.

Comment: What error does it give you? Are you sure that the difference is between `DateTime.Now` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, rather than the difference being between `Source` and `ConverterCulture`? (Odd as it would be, try specifying `Source` as `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, just to see if that still gives an error.)

Comment: It reproduces the problem on my end. I also tried what @JonSkeet suggested and the problem is indeed `CurrentCulture`. By the way `CurrentCulture`'s documentation says: `An object that represents the culture used by the current thread.`. Isn't this the problem? That there's no "current thread" at design time. `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`, `InstalledUICulture`, `InvariantCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` work fine. Only the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` are acting up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you did not ask for a workaround and I cannot answer your original question.

I still want to post my solution in case others, like me, stumble across your question looking for a workaround.

If you set your ConverterCulture in a CustomBinding class and use this CustomBinding instead of Binding in you xaml, it works at design time too.

```
public class CultureAwareBinding : System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
    public CultureAwareBinding()
    {
        ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }
}
```

You can use it in your xaml like this.

```
<TextBlock Text="{CultureAwareBinding Source={x:Static s:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=Date: {0:dddd, MMMM dd}}"/>
```

As an additional benefit this allows you to change the ConverterCulture later in one single place if needed. Also you can set other properties like StringFormat like this.

Comment: Although this indeed doesn't answer my question, it is still the best answer. I've tried it, and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this same behavior, and the best response is to regard CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture as something that is *not* avail at design-time unless you set it.
As with many other WPF presentation constructs, sometimes your view-model or other properties need to take the design-time into consideration so that your visual elements display as expected in your VS designer. For example, the Galasoft MVVM framework includes a IsDesignTime property. You can use that (or whatever your own framework provides) to special-case a property to, if IsDesignTime is true, set it to some value suitable for display. This is handy as, for example, when you want to see how it appears when you set that culture to other languages.

Thus for your example, assuming you are indeed using a MVVM type of architecture -- you may want to bind your TextBlock Text property to your own view-model property, and have *that* property attend to determining the current DateTime and the CurrentCulture.

One note: remember that with WPF on desktop applics, the Window or UserControl ctor is not executed within the design-time environment -- only at runtime. That can get confusing until you realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems not so long ago, I would highly suggest using this nugget packet for localisation. It is pretty easy to use.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfLocalizeExtension/

Example AssemblyName = Application

RessourceFile = MainApplication.resx

Ressource1Key1 = Test

If you are using MVVM here is some code snippet.

XAML

```
    xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
    lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
    lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="AssemblyName"
    lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="ressourceName"
```

Defining Content for label,button etc...

```
<Label Content="{lex:Loc AssemblyName:ResourceName:ResourceKey}">
<Label Content="{lex:Loc Application:MainApplication:Test}">
```

In ViewModel You want to bind your button to command FrenchUI,EnglishUI

```
private void FrenchUI()
    {
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.SetCurrentThreadCulture = true;
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = new CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Culture"])//fr-CA;
    }

    private void EnglishUI()
    {
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.SetCurrentThreadCulture = true;
        LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = new CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CultureUS"]);//en-US
    }
```